# Sikuli Screen constructor giving error :Cannot instatiate the type screen

Tags: java, maven, automation, sikuli

Sikuli dependency version in maven is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikuli-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to do coding for image comparison using Sikuli API but getting error on:

```
Screen s =new Screen();
```

even though `Screen()` constructor does exist for `Screen` class in Sikuli.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>snapshot</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
      <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I think what you are using point to another project.

Comment: On adding above given  code i am getting an error at <repositories>  and its just red cross without any definition so i am unable to interpret the reason for error .Please referr to screenshot attached above .Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://jar-download.com/?search_box=sikuli and download the jar.
Create java project and add build path.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
  <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```